# Why is the construction of istreams forbidden?

Tags: c++

Here's some code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

class A {
    int *m;
    std::istream in;
    A(int *m, std::string file): m{m}, in{std::ifstream{file}} { foo(); }
public:
    A(int *m): m{m}, in{std::cin} { foo(); }
    void foo() {}
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to do `g++ -std=c++14 main.cc`, what I end up getting is:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 main.cc
main.cc: In constructor ‘A::A(int*, std::__cxx11::string)’:
main.cc:11:62: error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected within this context
     A(int *m, std::string file): m{m}, in{std::ifstream{file}} { foo(); }
                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from main.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:613:7: note: declared protected here
       basic_istream(basic_istream&& __rhs)
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cc: In constructor ‘A::A(int*)’:
main.cc:13:33: error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected within this context
     A(int *m): m{m}, in{std::cin} { foo(); }
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from main.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:611:7: note: declared protected here
       basic_istream(const basic_istream&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cc:13:33: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
     A(int *m): m{m}, in{std::cin} { foo(); }
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from main.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:611:7: note: declared here
       basic_istream(const basic_istream&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know it is not possible to do any sort of assignment on an `istream`, but I at least thought that I could construct one, just like `ifstream` and others. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Even making `in` a reference results in this:

```
main.cc: In constructor ‘A::A(int*, std::__cxx11::string)’:
main.cc:11:62: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::basic_istream<char>’
     A(int *m, std::string file): m{m}, in{std::ifstream{file}} { foo(); }
                                                              ^
```

Why is this?

Comment: You can't copy `cin`, but you can store a reference to it. Simply make `in` a reference, and it should solve it. However, seeing your edit, you will have issues binding a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: @iz_ Ok, doing this: `const std::istream &in;` makes it compile, but am I losing anything by making it `const`? Because we're never going to assign to an `istream`, isn't it fine?

Comment: By reading from a stream, you are mutating it. `const` will make it so the stream can't be read from.

Comment: @iz_ Is there an elegant solution? How can you read from it, and have it as a member (own it)?

Comment: walnut's solution below looks good to me.

Comment: You need to learn about automated resource management by "smart pointers". Also, avoid complex temporaries (like stream objects) and avoid binding const reference to temporaries (except when dealing with IN arguments of function where copying is expensive).

Comment: @curiousguy I have used `unique_ptr` extensively in the past but never for streams. How do you  suggest using them for streams? Can you point to `std::cin`? Also, you want me to avoid `ifs{std::ifstream{file}}`? It seems fine to me...

Comment: `std::cin` is just another object so of course you can get a pointer to it; it's lifetime is not yours though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide whether `A` is supposed to own the stream.

If it does own the stream, then you cannot pass it `std::cin` and you need to store either `ifstream` directly or `unique_ptr<istream>` instead of an `istream`, because you want to allow derived types such as `ifstream`.

If it is non-owning, then you cannot create the instance in the constructor. Instead the caller needs to create and own the stream and pass a reference to it to your constructor. For this you should save a reference `istream&` instead of `istream` or `std::reference_wrapper<istream>` if you want to allow assignment for the class or alternatively a raw (non-owning) pointer `istream*`.

If you want to allow both, you can create a base class taking only a reference and then you can make a derived class that additionally constructs and owns the stream. Then whenever needed you would construct either the derived or the base class type depending on whether it should be owning or not.

```
class A {
    std::istream& in;
public:
    A() : A(std::cin) { }
    A(std::istream& in): in(in) { }
};

class B : public A {
    std::ifstream ifs;
public:
    B(std::string file) : A(ifs), ifs(file) { }
};
```

Maybe you want to make the classes polymorphic by giving `A` a virtual destructor and virtual member functions, in case you want to use the two classes with runtime polymorphism.

Alternatively you could template the class for an owning and one non-owning version. Or you could use a `std::variant` as member, which can save owning or non-owning types. Which solution is the best in your case, depends on how you intend to use the class.

Comment: In my particular case I do not have any inheritance or polymorphism. Is it possible for `A` to somehow read from `in`, where `in` could either be `std::cin` or 
an `ifstream` constructed on the fly? The only thing right now that might solve this seems to be having `ifs` as an additional member to `A`, and then when constructing `in`, we do `in(ifs)`. This does look somewhat redundant though.

Comment: @herophant Yes, you could certainly merge the two classes and have a reference and non-reference member or you could use `std::variant<std::unique_ptr<std::istream>, std::ifstream>` but using `std::variant` is a bit trickier and probably not worth it. A class template would make switching between the types also easy. Again, I don't know what exactly the requirements are.